# Perform sequelize findall in a huge array

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

everyone,

I am facing an issue with sequelize and mariadb.
I want to perform a findall(where : {myproperty : {$in: myArray}}) like this.
The fact is that for an array of like 200 values it works fine, but for an array of 700 it is not working any more.
Is this  problem in mariadb, or sequelize and thus maybe in my application the memory size i allow to node to work?
Thanks you!

Comment: I've seen an `IN()` with 70,000 values in MySQL.  So I don't think MariaDB has a problem.  Hence, I would point the finger at Sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of factors affects fetching large data issues. Memory issue on app side as data is kept in memory, network issues as large data has more chances of failure, indexing on DB column. If its memory or network issue you should use sequelize pagination https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-paginate